# S3 Lifecycle Policy Delete All Objects WITHOUT A Certain Tag Value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-object-tagging, s3-lifecycle-policy

While reading over [this S3 Lifecycle Policy document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html) I see that it's possible to delete an S3 object containing a particular *key=value* pair e.g.,

```
<LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        <Filter>
           <Tag>
              <Key>key</Key>
              <Value>value</Value>
           </Tag>
        </Filter>
        transition/expiration actions.
        ...
    </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

But is it possible to create a similar rule that deletes any object **NOT** in the *key=value* pair? For example, anytime my object is accessed I could update it's tag with the days current date e.g., `object-last-accessed=07-26-2019`. Then I could create a Lambda function that deletes the current S3 Lifecycle policy each day and then create a new lifecycle policy that has a tag for each of the last 30 days, then my lifecycle policy would automatically delete any object that has not been accessed in the last 30 days; anything that was accessed longer than 30 days would have a date value older than any value inside the lifecycle policy and hence it would get deleted.

Here's an example of what I desire (note I added the desired field `<exclude>`,

```
<LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        <Filter>
           <exclude>
              <Tag>
                 <Key>last-accessed</Key>
                 <Value>07-30-2019</Value>
              </Tag>
              ...
              <Tag>
                 <Key>last-accessed</Key>
                 <Value>07-01-2019</Value>
              </Tag>
           <exclude>
        </Filter>
        transition/expiration actions.
        ...
    </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

Is something like my made up `<exclude>` value possible? I want to delete any S3 Object that has not been accessed in the last 30 days (that's different than an object which is older than 30 days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this is possible but via a different mechanism.

My solution is to take a slightly different approach and set a tag on every object and then alter that tag as you need. 
So in your instance when the object is created set object-last-accessed to "default" do that through an S3 trigger to a piece of Lambda or when the object is written to S3.

When the object is accessed, then update the tag value to the current date.

If you already have a bucket full of objects, you can use S3 batch to set the tag to the current date and use that as a delta reference point from which to assume files were last accessed

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObjectTagging.html

Now set the lifecycle rule to remove objects with a tag of "default" after 10 days (or whatever you want).
Add additional rules to remove files with a tag of a date 10 days after that date. You will need to update the lifecycle rule periodically, but you can create 1000 at a time.
this doc gives details of the formal for a rule
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_LifecycleRule.html
I'd suggest something like this

```
<LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        <ID>LastAccessed Default Rule</ID>
        <Filter>
            <Tag>
                <Key>object-last-accessed</Key>
                <Value>default</Value>
            </Tag>
        </Filter>
        <Status>Enabled</Status>
        <Expiration>
            <Days>10</Days> 
        </Expiration>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
        <ID>Last Accessed 2020-05-19 Rule</ID>
        <Filter>
            <Tag>
                <Key>object-last-accessed</Key>
                <Value>2020-05-19</Value>
            </Tag>
        </Filter>
        <Status>Enabled</Status>
        <Expiration>
            <Date>2020-05-29</Date> 
        </Expiration>
    </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Reading further on this, as I'm faced with this problem, an alternative is to just use the object lock retention mode which allows you to set a default retention on a bucket and then change that retention period as the file is accessed. This works at an version level, i.e. each version is retained for a period not the whole file, so may not be suitable for all.  more details in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock-overview.html#object-lock-retention-modes

Comment: I'm tempted to do this but want to retain the right to override object locks and that doesn't seem possible.